# Modx change mime type for images

Tags: html, mime-types, content-type, mime, modx

have uploaded a webp image to my MODX website. seobility shows me that the content or mime type is missing. but i can't edit the html code of the image. thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

perhabs the images is corrupt you do not need to specify mime types in modx for images.

also if you use pthumb you can create a webp image optimised e.g.

[[pthumb? &input=`your path to your image` &options=`&h=100&w=100&zc=1&f=webp`]]

Answer (score 0):

It seems Seobility not MODX problem is.
You can directly specify this new type by with header adding it via "Content Type" page:
/manager/?a=system/contenttype